# I am trying to fit number of images in one div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, resize

[What I am trying to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQPg9.png)

I want to display multiple images in the same div of fixed size like the image. There will be multiple divs in the same page. The total size of the divs should not exceed the size of the screen.

```
 function setupView(div, items, height, percentage) {
       //get the height for the div

       //var max_height = getPossibleHeight(div, items);
       if(percentage){

    $(div).css("height" , $(window).height() / 100 * height);
  } else
  $(div).css("height" , height+"px");



  $(div).css("line-height",0);

  //get the computed height and width
  const div_height = $(div).height();
  const div_width = $(div).width();




  //Calculate the side of each image
  const im_side = parseInt(getItemSize(div_width, div_height, items));

  var count;
  var dv =  $(div);
  for(count=0; count <= items; count++){

    dv.append("<img style='height: "+ im_side +"px;"+" width: "+ im_side+"px" +"' src='../images/done.png'/>");
  }

}
function getItemSize(x, y, n) {
  var px = Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(n*x/y));
  var sx,sy;
  if(Math.floor((px*y)/x)*px < n){
    sx = y/Math.ceil(px*y/x);
  } else{
    sx = x/px;
  }
  var py = Math.ceil(Math.sqrt((n*y)/x));
  if(Math.floor((py*x)/y)*py<n){
    sy = x/Math.ceil((x*py)/y);
  }
  else {
    sy = y/py;
  }
  // alert("X="+sx + " Y="+sy);
  // if(x>y)
  return (sx>sy) ? sx : sy;

}
$(function() {

  setupView(".panel-4",25000,"60",true);
  // setupView(".panel-5",9000);

  alert("Load complete!");

});
```

This is what is happening right now:
[Current Situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iRpsX.png)

I have used the code provided on
[C Code](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/466198/algorithm-to-get-the-maximum-size-of-n-squares-that-fit-into-a-rectangle-with-a)
I want to resize the images in such a way that they fill the div completely without leaving any space.